# Tense for question with "penser"

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

"Do you think it would be a good idea to buy a new bike?"

> Pensez-vous que ___ une bonne idée d'acheter un nouveau vélo ?
>
> (1) c'est
>
> (2) ce soit
>
> (3) ce serait

Are all three choices acceptable? I guess the indicative can be used when the asker thinks that the answer is likely positive, the subjunctive when the asker thinks that the answer is likely negative, and the conditional is neutral?

Comment: Your description seems fine. (2) biased towards *non*, (1) and (3) more or less neutral, depending on prosody. NB. The subject inversion with *tu* sounds strange in France French (*tu* => informal, subject inverted questions => formal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three choices are acceptable but as it's translated from **"it would be"**, the correct form is *Pensez-vous que ce serait une bonne idée d'acheter un nouveau vélo ?*